# How to show list data into datagridview?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to bind a list of data to a data grid, but can't do it. I'm giving my code here.

I have made a class like this:

```
public class Book
{
    int bookID;
    string bookName;
    string athourName;

    public Book(int BookID, string BookName, string AuthorName)
    {


        bookID = BookID;
        bookName = BookName;
        athourName = AuthorName;

    }
}
```

Under form load event, I wrote the following code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Book Book1 = new Book(001, "Java", "Harbart");
        Book Book2 = new Book(002, "C", "Balaguru");

        string[] BookArray = new string[10];

        BookArray[0] = Book1.ToString();
        BookArray[1] = Book2.ToString();


        List<Book> Obj = new List<Book>();

        Obj.Add(Book1);
        Obj.Add(Book2);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = Obj;
    }
```

This doesn't give any error, but also not showing any data in the data grid. I have a feeling I'm missing something in between. A clarification on how to bind data to data grid would be very helpful.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you - to show to others that it did you can click the check mark my the arrows. When it is green it indicates that it is the accepted answer. Also once you have enough reputation you can upvote other answers that help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataGridView` requires public properties to autogenerate its columns. It will not work with fields, either public or private.

Change your class to this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int bookID { get; set; }
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public string athourName { get; set; }

    public Book(int BookID, string BookName, string AuthorName)
    {
        bookID = BookID;
        bookName = BookName;
        athourName = AuthorName;
    }
}
```

That uses auto-properties but you can of course use the longhand syntax as well.